# RSForm!Pro - Google Analytics Plugin causes duplicate GA code

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, rsform, google-analytics

If using the plug-in RSForm!Pro - Google Analytics Plugin to put in GA code on your forms, along with using Asynchronous Google Analytics plug-in, on those pages that has a form, there is a duplicate of the GA code. I was told that's problem it will mess up reports in GA.

So I am questioning, if RSForm!Pro - Google Analytics Plugin is even needed? If so, why?

Answer (score 2):

The RSForm!Pro - Google Analytics Plugin is used to register **posted forms** in Google Analytics.

It triggers a specific code on the thankyou page or thankyou message. With the plain Google Analytics code you would not be able to check if someone has filledin the form when you use the thankyou message. Because that would register the same page as the page where the form is on.

That's why.

Comment: But what about the duplicate GA code on the page? I see here it causes problems:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/gIIJsbr4hmg

Comment: Found this link https://www.ostraining.com/support-forum/joomla-support/implementing-adwords-code-using-rsforms/